# Ratio of a matrix's sample standard deviation to the sd of the matrix of its row averages approximately = the square root of the sample size?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, sampling, standard-deviation, mean

Given a large matrix, why is the ratio of a matrix's sample standard deviation and the standard deviation of the matrix of its row averages approximately equal to the square root of the sample size?

```
test <- matrix(rnorm(1600), 100, 16)
testRA <- apply(test, 1, mean)
sd(test)/sd(testRA)
```

What is the mathematical basis of this?

Comment: What you have done is (almost) discovered that, when drawing independent observations from a population, the standard deviation of the sample mean is equal to the standard deviation of the population divided by the sample size.  Is this what you are interested in learning about?

Comment: I just thought there is a mathematical formula for the row average, that i don't know. hopefully if i can manipulate the formula to show the ratio works out to be around sqrt(sample size). currently i think the sample size of the numerator is 16*100, and the sample size of the denominator is 100, so in the ratio, the 100 cancels out, and leaves just 16. However, standard deviation requires you to take the square root, so its just approx sqrt(16) = 4. i'm aware that i'm working with approx numbers since sample sd should be divided by n-1 instead, but i'm using n.

Comment: @jbow I believe you neglected to apply the square root to $1/n$ in both your comments.

Comment: @whuber - Argghhh, that's what I get for doing this while waiting for a response to work emails.

Comment: Rewritten comment: The formula is as you suspect: $\sigma(\bar{x}) = \sigma(x)/\sqrt{n}$,  where $\sigma(\cdot)$ is the standard deviation of $\cdot$, $x$ is a single observation, $\bar{x}$ is the sample mean, and $n$ is the sample size. It holds for independent samples from a given distribution, and actually more generally than that.

Comment: @jbowman thanks. I noticed it only works with row averages but not column average. not sure why. it was not how i originally learned it.

Comment: *Of course* it works with the column average, too.  Merely switch the "100" and the "16" in your code and take the transpose.  Perhaps you just haven't looked at enough examples.